# Capture clicking on a checkbox's title in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'd like to listen on the event of a user clicking on a checkbox's title (in addition to the checkbox itself). How can this be done?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you wrap the title in a `<label for="checkboxID">`, then clicking on the title will fire the checkbox's click event.

See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/snLfq/) for a quick example.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#myCheckbox').change(function(){ doStuff();});
$('#myCheckboxsLabel').click(function(){ doStuff();});
```

So long as you use the same `doStuff()` function for both, you should be ok

Answer (score 0):

If `<label for="id">` tags don't trigger your jQuery you may need a plugin to do it for you. Try labelify, I've heard good things (though not directly related to your question).